# Deploy Discord bot on vps (Plesk)

Tags: deployment, vps, plesk, discord.js

I have recently created a Discord bot in Javascript. I have bought a vps (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Plesk Web Host) and a domain name. How do I run a Discord Bot 24/7 on this server? I have tried putting the app.js in a subdomain but that of course didn't seem to work... 
I have enabled node.js

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just put the files on the server and run it? I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: Also, seeing it is in node.js I would recommend using the package forever (Which will keep the bot running always)

Comment: or pm2 instead of forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem! I've downloaded Jenkins so it automatically deploys. After that I deploy it using forever. If someone wants to do this too, here is the script for jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {nodejs "node"}

  stages {
      stage('start node') {
        steps {
            sh 'npm --prefix ./src install ./src'
            sh 'JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe forever stop ./src/app.js || true'
            sh 'JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe forever start ./src/app.js'
        }
     }
  }
}
```